# ¿Cómo agregar propiedades de manera dinámica, a un objeto con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando crear un chart, en donde se muestran los resultados de varias empresas (pueden ser muchas, o pocas). Para el chart, se debe introducir el valor de cada empresa, como se muestra a continuación (un ejemplo de 2):

```js
let data = [];

var categories = ['1. IDENTIFICACIÓN GENERAL', '2. CARACTERIZACIÓN DEL GERENTE', '3. FACTORES DE COMPETITIVIDAD', '4. DIAMANTE COMPETITIVO', '5. MERCADEO Y VENTAS', '6. TALENTO HUMANO (NIVEL DE DESEMPEÑO)', '7. CAPACIDAD TÉCNICA INTERNA Y EXTERNA DE LA EMPRESA'];

for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
  let value1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * (11 - 5)) + 5);
  data.push({
    category: categories[i],
    value1: value1
  })
}

chart.data = data;

series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.RadarSeries());
series1.dataFields.valueY = "value1";
series1.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
series1.strokeWidth = 3;
series1.tooltipText = "{valueY}";
series1.name = this.enterprises[j].nombreEmpresa_dato;
series1.bullets.create(am4charts.CircleBullet);
series1.dataItems.template.locations.dateX = 0.5;

series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.RadarSeries());
series2.dataFields.valueY = "value2";
series2.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
series2.strokeWidth = 3;
series2.tooltipText = "{valueY}";
series2.name = this.enterprises[j].nombreEmpresa_dato;
series2.bullets.create(am4charts.CircleBullet);
series2.dataItems.template.locations.dateX = 0.5;
```

El problema, es que sólo agrega `value1`, no sé cómo agregarle más `values` con respecto a la cantidad de empresas que llenen el formulario.

Comment: Haz probado ingresando un array?

Comment: Para eso está el data.push